# Object is not deallocated when capturing by closures in Swift

Tags: ios, closures, swift, dealloc

The Swift Programming Language guide has the following example:

```
class HTMLElement {

    let name: String
    let text: String?

    @lazy var asHTML: () -> String = {
        [unowned self] in
        if let text = self.text {
            return "<\(self.name)>\(text)</\(self.name)>"
        } else {
            return "<\(self.name) />"
        }
    }

    init(name: String, text: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
    }

    deinit {
        println("\(name) is being deinitialized")
    }

}
var paragraph:HTMLElement? = HTMLElement(name: "p", text: "hello, world")
println("\(paragraph!.asHTML())")
paragraph = nil
```

It was expected to print out the string in deinit() method, but it hadn't printed anything. It mean to me that the object is still alive, and has strong reference cycle with the closure. Does anyone get the same issue?

Comment: If this is in a playground, bear in mind that the playground environment seems to keep ahold of variables (presumably for printing them out and other debugging.) Try the same code in a real project and see if you get the expected results.

Comment: Thanks. I run the code on a real project in main.swift file

Answer (score 2):

Do this with weak capture instead of unowned

```
class HTMLElement {

    let name: String
    let text: String?

    @lazy var asHTML: () -> String = {
        [weak self] in
        if let text = self?.text {
            return "<\(self?.name)>\(text)</\(self?.name)>"
        } else {
            return "<\(self?.name) />"
        }
    }

    init(name: String, text: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
    }

    deinit {
        println("\(name) is being deinitialized")
    }

}
var paragraph:HTMLElement? = HTMLElement(name: "p", text: "hello, world")
println("\(paragraph!.asHTML())")
paragraph = nil
```

Comment: Thanks it worked as expected. However, my question is whey it does not work with "unowned" keyword, cause this keyword is basically similar to weak except that it does not allow optional value.

Comment: My guess would be a compiler bug, definitely worth filing

Comment: @LongNV accept the anwer if it is correct, and upvote it if it went above and beyond your expectations.